# Butter pecan fudge

Tags: fudge

I was making fudge. It called for white sugar and brown sugar to be added to butter and whipping cream. Bring to boil, cook for 5 minutes, THEN stir in confectioners sugar. I messed up and added the confectioners sugar with the other 2 before cooking!! Will my fudge still set up??

Comment: Welcome! Does your fudge have a step like “stir until it thickens” at the end?

Comment: It depends on the temperature it is cooked to; I use 234F which is a little high. In a hundred batches of fudge I never added confectioners sugar. I add nuts after it has reached 234 F ( off the heat).In my experience , if it does not set in about 15 minutes, it is not going to . Cooking time is no measure of temperature as burners and pots vary so dramatically.